# Css transition not working with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying a left bar hide/show with transition. Here's my code:

**JQuery:**

```
$("[data-toggle='offcanvas']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.left-side').toggleClass("collapse-left");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.left-side.collapse-left {
    left: -220px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
    <!-- my content-->
</aside>
```

Comment: then what is problem in code?

Comment: A reduced test case as a code snippet or a fiddle, perhaps? The code you've shown so far should work. However, I would suggest using `translate` so that you can potentially offload the rendering to GPU, and will not cause massive repainting.

Comment: may be your not added **[data-toggle='offcanvas']** to aside tag

Comment: tried to make a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99o4k67f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the css `left` property has no effect on elements in normal flow. You should *position* the element by setting a position property value other than *static* so that `left` takes effect.

Secondly, the transition happens from one value to another. So if you expect to see a transition, set a default value, for example `left:0`.

Finally, If you expect the element to animate when a class it removed, you should not add the `transition` property in the class being toggled, Instead set it using a static selector.

---

```js
$("#click").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.left-side').toggleClass("collapse-left");
});
```

```css
.left-side {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.left-side.collapse-left {
  left: -220px;
}
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #06F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">click</button>
<aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
  <div>This is test</div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/99o4k67f/1/

```
$("#click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.left-side').toggle('slow');
});
```

Or more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/99o4k67f/2/

```
$("#click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.left-side').animate({width:'toggle'},900);
});
```

Btw, you don't need any css for this :)

Comment: yah, but only collapse to left. not to top left corner

Comment: Lol @MamunSardar look at second fiddle ;)